# Smoothing of a 3d-geometry

Tags: matlab, plot, graphics, surface

```
figure
isovals = shiftdim(xPhys,2);
isovals = smooth3(isovals,'box',1);
patch(isosurface(isovals,0.8),'FaceColor',[0 0 1],'EdgeColor','none'); % blue
patch(isocaps(isovals,0.8),'FaceColor',[1 0 0],'EdgeColor','none');    % red
view(3); axis equal tight off; camlight;
```

The above code transforms this 3d-geometry [image: Picture 1]
in this geometry
[image: Picture 2]
xPhys (variable in the second line of the code) is a 3d matrix whose elements indicate the density of a square, zero means the square is empty, one means it is completely filled with material. And in between there are infinitely different intermediate levels.

I have created a code that causes there to be only one intermediate value (e.g. 0.5), this can be seen here as light grey. [image: Picture 3]

I would like to rewrite the code so that the last geometry shown is smoothed, but one should be able to distinguish the light grey from the black areas. In the code above, no distinction is made, all squares get the colour blue.

What can i do to achieve this goal?

Comment: Try https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well, in the above you are plotting an issurface, so by definition, there is only 1 value, thus "iso". The blue is not the full geometry, its a surface of the geometry at a very particular numerical value. Don't mistake visualization with the data

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thank you for the information. Do you have any idea how I can create a 'bisurface'?

Comment: make two  isosurfaces?